# Session and XMLHTTP

Tags: asp-classic

I have two asp pages on the same server. The first one generates XML dynamically using querystring informations and session information. The second one reads the first one using an XMLHTTP object and do things using the XML datas.

However, my problem is that the XMLHTTP request is done server-side. Thus, the session variables of the client are not accessible when the xml should be generated.

How can I do so that the page that generates the XML receives the session variables ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with what you are trying to do, not least is that it can lead a busy server to lock up entirely.

Here is the another approach.

Add a third page to your solution.  This page contains simply a function which returns an XML DOMDocument.  This function contains all the logic from your original xml generating page but builds the XML into the DOM (which you were probably doing all ready right?).

Now your original page simply includes this new function page, calls the function and sends the DOM to the response:

```
 <!-- #include file="xmlFunction.asp" -->
 <%
      Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
      Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
      GenerateXml().Save Response
 %>
```

Your client page can now look this

```
 <!-- #include file="xmlFunction.asp" -->
 <%
    . . .

    Dim dom: Set dom = GenerateXml()
    ''# Code that uses the XML in the dom.

 %>
```

No additional "Request to self" is needed hence no potential lock up.  Since code in the xmlFunction.asp is running as part of the original request the appropriate Session object is accessible.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I did not think of it since I am not the owner of the script that generate the xml but you remind me that developpers should communicate to make it work.